# Pandas Groupby based on several values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Dataframe. 
For simplicity, let's assume this is my df:

```
A B C
1 4 7
1 5 4
1 6 2
```

What I want to do, is to group by `A` and `B`, where one group of `B` is `[4,6]` and the other is `5`. 
Let's say my aggregation function is `Sum` on `C` so I want the result to be:

```
A   B  Sum(C)
1 [4,6]  9
1   5    4
```

I know I can add an additional column to indicate if the value is in [4,6], but is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so easy.

First I use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) for groupby by same values and then [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by custom function and `sum`:

```
#4 and 6 are same group
d = {4:6}
df = df.groupby(['A',df.B.replace(d)]) \
       .agg({'B':lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x) > 1 else x.iat[0], 'C':'sum'}) \
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True) \
       .reset_index() \
       .reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
   A       B  C
0  1       5  4
1  1  [4, 6]  9
```

If instead `list`s can be tuples:

```
#define groups of all values of column
d = {'a':[5], 'b':[4,6]}
#create tuples
d = {k: tuple(d[oldk]) for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{4: (4, 6), 5: (5,), 6: (4, 6)}

df = df.groupby(['A', df.B.map(d)])['C'].sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   A       B  C
0  1  (4, 6)  9
1  1    (5,)  4
```

Comment: Pretty messy... but I guess it works. Thanks! Is there no cleaner way to do this? :(

Comment: I am thinking about it... Not sure.

Comment: Do you need in `B` lists? Or there can be also tuples?

Comment: There can be tuples.

Comment: And another question, is possible define groups by `dict` like `d = {'a':[5], 'b':[4,6]}` ?

Answer (score -1):

Try df.groupby(["A","B"]).sum()

Comment: Clearly not! Sorry about that. Where is the information about the grouping values for column B held?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts anyway.